# Running cross browser tests using selenium and .NET Core

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, xunit.net

I would like to run UI tests on multiple browsers using selenium and .NET Core and xUnit. I found few examples that are using `nUnit`'s  `TestFixture` attribute. However, i am particularity looking for `xUnit` solution.

I found [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/improving-the-xunit-net-browser-attribute/) solution where i can create my own attribute derived from `DataAttribute`

```
public class BrowserAttribute : DataAttribute
{
    private IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

    public BrowserAttribute(string browser, string url)
    {
        switch (browser)
        {
            case "Chrome":
                Driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
             case "IE":
                Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
             case "Firefox":
                Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
        }
        Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        Goto(url);
    }

    public void Goto(string url)
    {
        Driver.Url = url;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
    {
        return new[] { new object[] { Driver } };
    }
}
```

and then Test would look like

```
[Theory]
[Browser("IE", "http://www.google.co.uk")]
[Browser("Firefox", "http://www.google.co.uk")]
[Browser("Chrome", "http://www.google.co.uk")]
public void Test(IWebDriver driver)
{
    // Test something with IWebDriver    

    // i can do driver.Close() here to dispose IWebDriver        
}
```

This would work
However, it will not dispose IWebDriver after test is complete, unless i explicitly invoke Close() in every test

What would be the best option here to invoke Close() on IWebDriver?

**Update1**

I created custom attribute derived from `BeforeAfterTestAttribute` and applied that attribute at class level. and it Worked. However, when it invokes `GetCustomAttributes(..)` it re-executes the test

```
public class AfterTest : Xunit.Sdk.BeforeAfterTestAttribute
{
    public override void After(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        //at line below the test get executed again
        var attributes = methodUnderTest.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BrowserAttribute),true);

        var att = attributes.First() as BrowserAttribute;
        att.Driver.Close();
        base.After(methodUnderTest);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get instance of IWebDriver in `After` method?

Comment: I'd have a scan of the xunit slack to see if anyone else has ventured an approach. (Wild guess: Perhaps with MemberData you could Dispose after each one is used?)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, XUnit does not support [TearDown] methods the way that NUnit does. More information on how to implement something like this in XUnit can be found here: http://mrshipley.com/2018/01/10/implementing-a-teardown-method-in-xunit/

In case you decide you'd like to use NUnit instead, you can refer to this code here. I've implemented my own version of a TestFixture that is responsible for creating WebDriver instances to begin a test, and closing the instance as needed. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace MyTestAutomation.Framework
{
    public class BaseTestFixture
    {
       // this is your singleton webdriver instance -- this gets used throughout the testcase
        public static AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement> Driver { get; private set; }

        [SetUp]
        public void BaseTestInitialize()
        {     
            // create webdriver instance here
            Driver = DriverFactory.Current.Create();

            // call test initialize, which can get overridden in each test case class    
            TestInitialize();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void BaseTestCleanup()
        {
            // implement TestCleanup() override in your test case class
            TestCleanup(); // clean up after test case -- delete data, etc.

            // universal cleanup: close & quit driver
            Driver.Close();
            Driver.Quit();
        }

        protected virtual void TestInitialize()
        {
            // override this method in your test class & write initialize steps
        }

        protected virtual void TestCleanup()
        {
           // override this method in your test class & write additional cleanup steps
        }
    }
}
```

To use this in action, your test class needs to inherit `BaseTestFixture`, like this:

```
public class MyTestClass : BaseTestFixture
{
    protected override void TestInitialize()
    {
        // initialize your test case here
        // no need to create webdriver, base class method already does this
        // do something like log in to your application here, or navigate to URL
    }

    [Test]
    public void MyTest()
    {
    }

    protected override void TestCleanup()
    {
        // clean up your test case here -- log out, delete data, etc.
        // no need to implement Driver.Close(), base class method already does it 
    }
}
```

With this code sample, you can write a test fixture that handles creating a WebDriver instance & closing it before and after every test. You can override `TestInitialize` and `TestCleanup` if you wish to implement more specific steps at the start and end of each test case. NUnit's `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` methods ensure these initialize / cleanup methods will only be run before & after each test case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use using Xunit.Abstractions; and use the Dispose method. The code below also permits console output, a serious pain point with xunit is not having that.

```
public class MyTestClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper print;


    public MyTestClass(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        this.print = output;
        print.WriteLine("I'm the tear up");

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        print.WriteLine("I'm the tear down");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest1()
    {

        print.WriteLine("This is output from test 1");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest2()
    {

        print.WriteLine("This is output from test 2");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyTest3()
    {

        print.WriteLine("This is output from test 3");
    }


}
```